# Tokenized strings to get integers from a file

Tags: php, fgets, strtok

i have a file.dat and its format is

```
1303100643 115.83
1303100644 115.94
1303100645 115.80
1303100646 115.99
1303100647 115.74
1303100648 115.11
```

here is the php code where i am trying to get the right integer for example in the first line i would like to get only the value "115"

```
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle, 1024);
    $reading=strtok($line_of_text[0]," ");
    echo $reading[0];
}
```

if i use `reading[0]` result is just `"1"`

On `reading[1]` it gives error

> "SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for( ! )
>
> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\Delta Compression\MaxLength.php on line 16"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `strtok()` appropriately. `strtok()` is initialized and then each subsequent call gives you the next *token*. So `$reading[0]` is really pulling the first character of the string.

You're using [`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) like `explode()`, so just use `explode()`:

```
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle, 1024);
    $reading=explode(" ", $line_of_text[0]);
    echo $reading[0];
}
```

> i would like to get only the value "115"

You could simply cast the result to an `int` or use [`int_val()`](http://php.net/int_val):

```
echo (int)$reading[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions would be faster

```
$data = file_get_contents("file.txt");
preg_match_all("/([0-9]{10}) ([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2})/",$data,$Matches);

//Use below if you want an associative array with the first 10 numbers 
//being the keys and the second numbers being the values
$myData = array_combine($Matches[1],$Matches[2]);
```

`([0-9]{10})` Matches the first 10 numbers 0-9,

`([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2})` Matches the next set of numbers that has 3 number 0-9 then a period then 2 more numbers 0-9

$Matches will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1303100643 115.83
            [1] => 1303100644 115.94
            [2] => 1303100645 115.80
            [3] => 1303100646 115.99
            [4] => 1303100647 115.74
            [5] => 1303100648 115.11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1303100643
            [1] => 1303100644
            [2] => 1303100645
            [3] => 1303100646
            [4] => 1303100647
            [5] => 1303100648
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 115.83
            [1] => 115.94
            [2] => 115.80
            [3] => 115.99
            [4] => 115.74
            [5] => 115.11
        )

)
```

code vs code:

**JasonMcCreary**

```
$time1=microtime();
$mydata = array();
$file_handle = fopen("data.txt","r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle, 1024);
    $reading=explode(" ", $line_of_text);

    $mydata[] = $reading;
}
fclose($file_handle);
$time2 =microtime();
```

**Reading line by line and using explode**

```
1374728889 0.20137600  :: 1374728889 0.20508800 
0.20508800
0.20137600
----------
0.00371200
```

**Mine**

```
$time1=microtime();

$data = file_get_contents("data.txt");
preg_match_all("/([0-9]{10}) ([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2})/",$data,$Matches);
$myData = array_combine($Matches[1],$Matches[2]);

$time2=microtime();

echo $time1." :: ".$time2;
```

**Using fgc and regular expressions**

```
1374728889 0.20510100  :: 1374728889 0.20709000 
0.20709000
0.20510100
----------
0.00198900
```

Comment: While it works, I am not sure a regular expression is the right tool for the job.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary, How so? less code, more clear what is going on, and he could simply use `array_combine` to make an associative array: `$myData = array_combine($Matches[1],$Matches[2]);` seems to be the right tool.

Comment: if you're comfortable with regexes, a regex is the **perfect** tool for this job, assuming input is reliably consistent (which it appears to be). less typing is always nice.

Comment: @Patrick Evans, obviously it's less code. More clear is true only if you are familiar with regular expressions. Regardless, you said *faster*. And I challenge you to prove it.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary think he meant faster to *type* (of course regexes typically aren't faster than string functions)

Comment: @sgroves, for someone advocating clarity, they should be more clear. :) You will find that while regexes are indeed powerful, they are not always the right tool for the job.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary i already know that, i barely ever use regexes :P i just think they *are* a good tool for this job. there's lots and lots of ways to do this particular example that are equally good ... just comes down to preference

Comment: @JasonMcCreary, edited answer to show speed comparison, your code ran in 0.00371200 and mine in 0.00198900 on my server, using a file with 768 entries, and i did mean faster speed wise, not in typing

Comment: @Patrick Evans, I appreciate the benchmark. But keep in mind the OP's code is far from optimized. When it is, I guarantee your code is slower. Especially for larger file sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into file() and explode().  File() will read each line of the file into an array for you, then you can use explode() for the space and decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), as other answers have suggested, or you could get the positions of the space and decimal point and use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the characters between them. Assuming your input is consistent, either [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) or [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) will work for this:

```
$line = '1303100643 115.83';

$space_pos   = strrpos($line, ' ');
$decimal_pos = strrpos($line, '.');

$number = substr($line, $space_pos, $space_pos + count($line) - $decimal_pos);
```

---

Another approach would be get everything after the space, then take its floor or cast it to an integer. Fortunately, you can do this in an easy to read one-liner using the same functions as the previous example:

```
$number = (int)substr($line, strrpos($line, ' '));
```

---

Or you could use a regular expression, which is probably your easiest option here if you're familiar with regex:

```
if (preg_match('|(\d+)(\.\d+)?$|', $line, $matches)) {
    $number = $matches[0];
}
```

Breaking that regex down ...

- `(` - open group (contents go into `$matches[0]`)
- `\d+` - match one or more digits
- `)` - close capture group
- `(` - open another group (we are going to make this group optional)
- `\.` - match a literal `.`
- `\d+` - match one or more digits
- `)` - close capture group
- `?` - make the preceding group optional (this permits strings like `1303100650 115`, if needed)
- `$` - match end of string

These examples are just for one string. Obviously, you'll want to do this in a loop (or just use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)).